# Selecting "not matching" data

Tags: regex

With the expression below, I can find all the data that contains `ToolTipML` within the curly brackets. But what I am trying to do is selecting all the data that doesn't contain `ToolTipML`. Can anyone please point out what I am missing?

```
({[^{}]*?)(ToolTipML)([^}]*})
```

here is an example https://regex101.com/r/bNq6kV/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sadly, regex has no pattern negation, however a popular hack is to use repeated pattern of any-match, lookahead and then any-match.

For example, in your case the regex is
`(?s)\{(?:.(?!ToolTipML).)+?\}`

We ensure that every character of input is not preceeded nor followed by the banned pattern.
The drawback is that most regex implementations do not support variable-length lookahead/lookbehind patterns, but in your case it works [flawlessly](https://regex101.com/r/bNq6kV/2).

This is a popular question and it was [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/5265595) with more detail and explanations

Comment: thank you anton, I was using only single pattern of lookbehind and it was selecting all the data, but this works flawlessly as you said

Comment: The `\{(?:(?<!ToolTipML)[^}])+\}` is not correct as [it matches `{...}`](https://regex101.com/r/xf1C0e/1) that may contain `ToolTipML`.

Comment: Yup, it does match when `ToolTipML` is exactly behind the `}`. Fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

I I understood you correctly, then you might use a negative lookahead:

`{((?!ToolTipML)[^{}])*}`

https://regex101.com/r/bNq6kV/3

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried that before and it is selecting everything,
 here is an example https://regex101.com/r/bNq6kV/1